# Nested Lambda Capture in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, lambda

I have something like:

```
// think of Synonym as a set/vector of values
// the purpose of this function is to filter out elements from the 2 synonyms/sets,
// that are not related (similar to SQL inner join) - modifier modifies vars
void Clauses::modifies(Synonym& modifiers, Synonym& modifiedVars, UnaryPredicate isModifies) {
    // filter out any modifiers that does not modify (is related to) any of the variables in modifiedVar (left join)
    modifiers.removeIf([modifiedVars, &isModifies](int line) -> bool {
        return modifiedVars.none([line, &isModifies](int v) -> bool { 
            return isModifies(line, v);
        });
    });

    // filter out any candidate modifiedVars that is not modified by any modifiers (right join)
    modifiedVars.removeIf([modifiers, &isModifies](int varIndex) -> bool {
        return modifiers.none([varIndex, &isModifies](int line) -> bool {
            return isModifies(line, varIndex);
        });
    });

    // result is an something like an SQL inner join
}
```

Problem is Visual Studio complains that:

```
Error   1   error C3480: 'PQL::Clauses::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda1>::isModifies': a lambda capture variable must be from an enclosing function scope   h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\spa_cpp\spa\pql.cpp   78
Error   2   error C2665: 'PQL::Clauses::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda3>::<lambda3>' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types h:\dropbox\sch\cs3202\spa_cpp\spa\pql.cpp   78
...
```

Originally, the code does not pass the predicates/conditions as references but reading somewhere I thought I needed it, but it didn't seem to change anything

```
modifiers.removeIf([modifiedVars, isModifies] ...
```

**UPDATE**: I am using VS2010 for this project

Comment: Seems to be a Visual Studio bug. GCC and Clang accept this kind of capture.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? [Nested lambda functions lose scope](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/537366/c-nested-lambda-functions-lose-scope) looks like the bug.

Comment: @JesseGood Ah snap, I just realized I'm not at home and here I'm using VS2010 rather than the latest VS2012 CTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2010, your code could be triggering a bug which doesn't allow you to capture a variable in a nested lambda.

Try using a default capture mode (e.g. [&] instead) as a workaround.

This bug is fixed in VS2012.

Comment: Actually what does `[&]` mean? I see it in afew places but dont understand what does it actually do

Comment: It means capture everything by reference, and `=` means capture everything by value

Comment: It means that you implicitly capture all objects that you refer to in the body of the lambda via reference.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a Visual C++ bug, as GCC and Clang accept this capture.
Here's a workaround:

```
modifiedVars.removeIf([modifiers, &isModifies](int varIndex) -> bool {
    auto& isModifiesRedirect = isModifies;
    return modifiers.none([varIndex, &isModifiesRedirect ](int line) -> bool {
        return isModifiesRedirect (line, varIndex);
    });
```

Note: I could only test this on VS2010. It might be fixed in VS2012. You may want to consider searching Microsoft Connect and submitting a new bug if it's not a known issue already.